# How can I kick off a Jenkins job when a new branch is made in gitlab?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I would like to initialize an environment when a new branch is created.  I would not like to run a job every time something is committed, only when it is a new branch.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I went with is to put logic into my jenkinsfile. Since I'm building the multibranch pipeline from one. I added the logic below...

```
stage('Deploy') {
   steps {
       script {
          if (env.BUILD_NUMBER == '1') {
            build job: 'new env'
           }else{
            build job: 'deploy'

            }
        }
    }
}
```